# Dump from a managed postgresql instance with ssl and ssl mode required

Tags: postgresql, ssl, digital-ocean, pg-dump

Hello fellow programmers,

I am trying to dump from a postgres instance which is requiring me to connect with a ssl certificate. The problem that occurs is that the `--sslcert` and `--sslmode` that exists on older documentation for `pg_dump` doesn't seem to exist for version 14 (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-ssl.html).

My question is how can I dump a database from such a database that is requiring users to have a certificate?

I cannot install anything on the server since it's managed. Connecting through `psql` works fine with ssl so I am kind of confused.

Thanks in advance for your sage advice and better wisdom

Comment: "Connecting through psql works fine with ssl so I am kind of confused."  Yeah, so am I.  psql and pg_dump handle ssl in the same way, so it is a mystery.  What is the error message?  Have the real binaries been replaced with wrappers?

Comment: I don't see that there ever has been `--sslmode` or `--sslcert`, either documented or coded.

Comment: @jjanes I saw some older SO threads in my searching spree I saw some commands like that and they linked to the docs where I also saw it. I don't have the link anymore since I closed it a while ago. It was for pg_restore though but I thought it should probably function the same way. The error I got was that there was no such command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a connection string with the `-d` option:

```sh
pg_dump -d 'sslmode=require sslcert=/my/certificate host=xyz' -F c -f dumpfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error of `pg_dump: error: invalid connection option "'sslmode"` and reading through the help docs of pg_dump it seems like the -d is for the database name?

Comment: Is this PostgreSQL? If yes, what version? Read the documentation again; it says that you can use a connect string with `-d`.

Comment: Yes but I was running it through a python script but it seems like it works in terminal.. now I just have to figure what goes wrong between these two. It probably strips something off for some reason..